# MongoDB aggregate Java API doesnt return results

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I am using the Java API for connecting to my DB. I am using the new Classes to connecto since the ones in almost all examples are marked deprecated
I use MongoClient to connect to MongoDatabase db. After that I do:

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("collName");
AggregateIterable<Document> res = collection.aggregate(myquery);
for(Document d : res)
{
    System.out.println(d.toJson());
}
```

It doesn't print anything. I tried to use result.first() too but it only prints null.

Now the reason I don't post specifics about my data an query is the following. If I look in the the log file in /var/log/mongodb I see the translated query. If I post THE EXACT query into the mongo shell. It just works like a charm. I found a post on here the says that the order of my aggregate functions could be a problem but that doesn't make sense if it works if pasted in the shell.

So here is my little altered query

```
Document sort = new Document("$sort", new Document("Day", 1));

    Document matchBeforeUnwindDayOfTheWeek = new Document("Day", day);

    Document matchBeforeUnwindVar1 = new Document("'value.Data'", new Document("$elemMatch",
            new Document("var1", new Document("$gt", minvar1).append("$lt", maxvar1))));        
    Document matchBeforeUnwindVar2 = new Document("'value.Data'", new Document("$elemMatch",
            new Document("var2", new Document("$gt", mingvar2).append("$lt", maxvar2))));

    List<Document> matchBeforeUnwindAnd = new LinkedList<Document>(); 
    matchBeforeUnwindAnd.add(matchBeforeUnwindDayOfTheWeek);
    matchBeforeUnwindAnd.add(matchBeforeUnwindVar1);
    matchBeforeUnwindAnd.add(matchBeforeUnwindVar2);

    Document matchBeforeUnwind = new Document("$match", new Document("$and", matchBeforeUnwindAnd));

    Document unwind = new Document("$unwind", "$value.Data");

    Document matchAfterUnwindVar1 = new Document("'value.Data.var1'",
            new Document("$gt", minvar1).append("$lt", minvar1));
    Document matchAfterUnwindVar2 = new Document("'value.Data.var2'",
            new Document("$gt", minvar2).append("$lt", maxvar2));

    List<Document> matchAfterUnwindAnd = new LinkedList<Document>(); 
    matchAfterUnwindAnd.add(matchAfterUnwindVar1);
    matchAfterUnwindAnd.add(matchAfterUnwindVar2);

    Document matchAfterUnwind = new Document("$match", new Document("$and", matchAfterUnwindAnd));

    Document groupFields = new Document("_id", "$_id");
    groupFields.put("Grouped", new Document("$push", "$value.Data"));

    Document group = new Document("$group", groupFields);

    List<Document> query = new LinkedList<Document>();
    query.add(sortByDayOfTheWeek);
    query.add(matchBeforeUnwind);
    query.add(unwind);
    query.add(matchAfterUnwind);
    query.add(group);

    AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(query);
```

Edit:
I tried it with a very simple query like the one posted below. Queries still translate fine in the log file.

Comment: Well the problem is likely in the aggregation pipeline definition, and that is completely absent in your question. Please edit your question.

Comment: Yes but how could that be? I mean I can see my pipeline in the log file after it executes and if I copy paste it in the shell it just works.

Comment: I think the point I was making is "we" cannot see it. How about sharing as maybe ( likely ) there is a problem there that you don't see but someone else will

Comment: Ok sorry about that but I had to change a couple of things in the code but here it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the '' characters. I thought I needed them because of the .-operator. Oh well. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1):

With the [ref. of mongo java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/) you should change `for` statement as below :

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
 MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("demo");
 MongoCollection < Document > collection = database.getCollection("collectionName");
 AggregateIterable < Document > res = collection.
 aggregate(asList(
     new Document("$match", new Document("_id", new ObjectId("55a8ad7f68d7f0852ea1c8a7")))));

 res.forEach(new Block < Document > () {
       @Override
     public void apply(final Document document) {
         System.out.println(document.toJson());
     }
 });
```

Comment: I tried that but it did not help. If I look into the logfile I see that the reslen is very small for the return to the java application. So it doesn't seem to be a problem with me processing but the return value.

Comment: Ohh and I am fairly sure the server really is doing the aggregation since the time needed are pretty much the same for the shell and the API

Comment: is better way to post your query formation code, because I tested the above code and it work fine.

Comment: Is it possible that the following could create a problem. I use BasicDBObjects for the query, but the return value is documents. Is it possible that that could cause problems?

Comment: so problem in your query formation changed to `BasicDBObjects` to `new Document` for reference check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but that didn't work. I posted the query above